Spark Connect set checkpoint directory
I have a setup to run jobs/code on Databricks clusters from a local IDE during development using spark connect. For the most part spark connect is essentially the same as an older spark session if used with the Dataframe api. But spark connect still does not support a sparkContext. So for operations requiring sparkContext the spark connect does not work. For example, we create a checkpoint directory using:
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/FileStore/checkpoint")

The above does not work. How can we perform operations like these if trying to test databricks stuff from local IDE using spark connect?

Have you tried setting the checkpoint directory using spark.conf.set() instead? It is supported in spark connect.

Which IDE are you using? How did you make the connection from your IDE to Databricks?

I am using VS Code and using Databricks connect to make connection from IDE to Databricks. Also spark.conf.set probably cannot set checkpoint dir: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.setCheckpointDir.html
